# Who is the figure Aktakshya, quoted in the Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, shatapatha-brahmana, sama-veda, rishi

The Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda, in a passage that simultaneously discusses the creation of the world and the way to properly conduct a yagna (fire-ritual), [quotes two individuals](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe41/sbe4129.htm) concerning the laying of bricks in a yagna:

> Here now Âktâkshya used to say, "Only he who knows abundant bricks possessed of (special) prayers, should build up the fire (altar): abundantly indeed he then heals Father Pragâpati."  But Tândya used to say, "Surely the bricks possessed of prayers are the nobility, and the space-fillers are the peasants; and the noble is the feeder, and the peasantry the food; and where there is abundant food for the feeder, that realm is indeed prosperous and thrives: let him therefore pile up abundant space-fillers!" Such then was the speech of those two, but the settled practice is different therefrom.

But my question isn't about the content of these quotations, but rather about who is quoted.  I assume that Tandya is the eponymous seer of the [Tandya Mahabrahmana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchavimsha_Brahmana) of the Sama Veda, so presumably his quotation is taken from the Tandya Brahmana.  (Can anyone verify this?)

My question is, who is Aktakshya, the other individual who's quoted?  Is he the seer of one of the Brahmanas of the Vedas?  Is his quotation taken from some other work that he is either the seer or the author of?